# Best (most performant) way to declare (class) properties with unknown values in v8

Tags: javascript, v8

So I learned a bit about the hidden class concept in v8. It is said that you should declare all properties in the constructor (if using prototype based "pseudo classes") and that you should not `delete` them or add new ones outside of the constructor. So far, so good.

1) But what about properties where you know the *type* (that you also shouldn't change) but not the (initial) *value*?

For example, is it sufficient to do something like this:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.myString;
    this.myNumber;
}
```

... and assign concrete values later on, or would it be better to assign a "bogus" value upfront, like this:

```
var Foo = function () {
    this.myString = "";
    this.myNumber = 0;
}
```

2) Another thing is with objects. Sometimes I just *know* that an object wont have a fixed structure, but I want to use it as a hash map. Is there any (non verbose) way to tell the compiler I want to use it this way, so that it isn't optimized (and deopted later on)?

**Update**

Thanks for your input! So after reading your comments (and more on the internet) I consider these points as "best practices":

- Do define *all* properties of a class in the constructor (also applies for defining simple objects)
- You have to assign *something* to these properties, even if thats just `null` or `undefined` - just stating `this.myString;` is apparently not enough
- Because you have to assign something anyways I think assigning a "bogus" value in case you can't assign the final value immediatly cannot hurt, so that the compiler does "know" ASAP what type you want to use. So, for example `this.myString = "";`
- In case of objects, do assign the whole structure if you know it beforehand, and again assign dummy values to it's properties if you don't know them immediatly. Otherwise, for example when intending to use the Object as a hashmap, just do: `this.myObject = {};`. Think its not worth indicating to the compiler that this should be a hashmap. If you *really* want to do this, I found a trick that assigns a dummy property to this object and `delete`s it immediatly afterwards. But I won't do this.
- As for smaller Arrays it's apparently recommended (reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw&feature=youtu.be&t=25m40s) to preallocate them especially if you know the final size, so for example: `this.myArray = new Array(4);`
- Don't `delete` properties later on! Just `null` them if needed
- Don't change types after assigning! This will add another hidden class and hurt performance. I think thats best practice anyways. The only case where I have different types is for certain function arguments anyways. In that case I usually convert them to the same target type.
- Same applies if you keep adding additional properties later on.

That being said, I also think doing this will lean to cleaner and more organized code, and also helps with documenting.

Yeah, so one little thing I am unsure remains: What if I define properties in a function (for example a kind of `configure()` method) called within the constructor?

Comment: If you do `this.myString;` the compiler probably does `this.myString = undefined` for you, or at least something similar. Reassigning a value to a property takes literally nanoseconds, so does it really matter ?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what happens. But the question is if 1) thats enough in respect to hidden classes, and 2) if assigning something with the intended type _immediatly_ is better than doing it later on.

Comment: 1) Hidden classes is just V8 creating a "hidden" class in the background somewhere, to make property lookups really fast. Every time you add a new property, the "hidden" class is recreated. In other words, if you're going to create a property, it takes about the same amount of time regardless of how you create it. But, you can create the properties in advance, and take advantage of the fast lookups you get when assigning values later, but that doesn't really matter with a few properties, or in code where the creation and assignment of the properties makes the browser wait for both anyway etc.

Comment: 2) if you already know the value, there's no point in first declaring the variable, and then a few lines down assign the value, you might  as well do both the first time, but in real life it most likely doesn't matter performance wise.

Comment: Of course I do not declare a variable and assign a value a few lines later. The point is that I assign the actual value _much_ later, in another method. And still not sure if just doing something like `this.myString;` is really enough. Just did a little test using `console.dir(Foo)`, and in fact I do NOT see the property in this case. But, if I write `this.myString = undefined;` I DO see the property, so apparently it isnt the same.

Comment: @adeneo I think that the idea here is can the engine optimize the fact that, say, `myNumber` is an integer and if so, will initializing it as an integer aid in such optimizations. Furthermore, does *not* initializing it with a given value then assigning to it later cause any sort of de-optimization due to incorrect assumptions made by the compiler? OP: feel free to correct me if any of that is incorrect.

Comment: @MikeC - I believe it's about the hidden classes in V8, and the fact that V8 will create hidden classes to aid in property lookups, and the OP is somehow wanting to capitalize on that by defining the properties in advance. Of course, when you think about it, `this.myString;` probably doesn't do anything at all, as it's not really a declaration, not like say `let something;`, where the value is set to `undefined`, etc. To have any chance of using the hidden classes a value most likely *must* be set, like `this.myString = null` *(or anything really)*. I don't think type matters at all.

Comment: @adeneo Looks like you're mostly right: ["v8 passes around 32-bit numbers to represent **all** values for improved efficiency"](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf/blob/master/data-types.md#efficiently-representing-values-and-tagging) (emphasis mine). There is a special case for small integers though: "bottom bit reserved as tag to signify if value is a SMI (small integer) or a pointer to an object". So in 99% of all cases, it doesn't really matter if you initialize the value up front or not.

Comment: And here's at least a short article on how hidden classes can be used for performance -> http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-hidden-classes-in-v8:4c7e81e4-1330-4398-8bd2-761bcbdd56cb

Comment: And here, more to the point of what the OP seems to be doing -> https://gist.github.com/twokul/9501770

Comment: Now, I think if someone wants to take advantage of hidden classes, it really seems that you _have_ to assign something, even if its only `null`or `undefined`. Assigning nothing does not seem to create the property and this is important for that mechanism to work, since creating all properties in the constructor is mandatory (thats one thing I am pretty sure about). So I guess this part of the question is answered. Now, the remaining question would be if it's better to assign _something_ with the intended _type_, even it's only a kind of bogus value to be replaced later on.

Comment: Ah, and its also still unclear to me how to declare an Object that should _not_ be optimized (for example if it's a hashmap that can't be optimized anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1): Just reading properties, like in your first snippet, does not do anything to the object. You need to assign them to create the properties.

But for *object* properties it doesn't actually matter much what values you initialise them with, as long as you do initialise them. Even `undefined` should be fine.

The concrete values are much more relevant for *arrays*, where you want to make sure to create them with the right elements (and without any holes!) because the VM tries to keep them homogeneous. In particular, never use the `Array` constructor, because that creates just holes.

Re 2): There are ways to trick the VM into using a dictionary representation, but they depend on VM and version and aren't really reliable. In general, it is best to avoid using objects as maps altogether. Since ES6, there is a proper Map class.

Comment: Think this is a good answer, but: according to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw&feature=youtu.be&t=25m40s its better to preallocate "small Arrays" even if you don't fill them immediatly. So as I understand it should be fine to use the `Array` constructor in this case.

Comment: @frontend_dev, well yes, true, but if you possibly can (i.e., know the size of the array statically), it is better to use an array literal with dummy values instead.